# Assuming Slope in Slope-Intercept Form [Clarification]

Tags: slope

So when learning about slope-intercept form, the equation that was used looked like this: $y = 2x + 3$, it then displayed a graph where the slope was going up by two and across by one. What I need a bit of clarification on is that do we just assume that the slope is, in this case, $\frac{2}{1}$, or is there something else?

Comment: The standard slope intercept form of an equation is given by y= mx + b, where m is the slope of the line, and (0, b) is the point at which the line crosses the y-axis, so b is also known as the y-intercept.

Comment: So your line intersects the point $(0, 3)$ and has a slope of m = 2.  Another point can be found to graph that line by going from $(0, 3),$ up two units, and over to the right one unit, to give you the second point $(0+1, 3+2) = (1, 5)$.

Comment: That part I understand but what I want to know is if given a whole number for slope, in this case, it's 2, do I just assume that it would be 2/1 in fraction form?

Comment: Yes, because $\frac 21 = 2$.

Comment: Ah okay! Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Glad to help out!!

Comment: The nice thing about slope is that if, instead of $\frac{2}{1}$, you had expressed $2$ as $\frac{4}{2}$ and drawn your line with "up $4$, over $2$", you would draw the same line.

Comment: That's pretty interesting!

Answer (score 1):

The standard slope intercept formula (that I was taught) is y=mx+b the variable m is your slope and the variable b is your intercept. In this case, m=2 meaning the slope is 2/1 and b=3 meaning the slope crosses the y-axis at (0,3) So, you were right when assuming the slope was 2/1. I hope this was helpful.